# How to handle import error with streamlit in python

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, streamlit

I am trying to print custom error message on the UI using `streamlit` if in case of import error.

Here is a simple code:

```
import streamlit as st
try:
    from google.auth import default
    from google.cloud import bigquery
except ImportError:
    st.write("Reauthentication is needed.")
    st.stop()


import pandas as pd
import base64



st.set_page_config(layout="wide")
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
credentials, project_id = default()
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project="project")
st.title('Tool')
st.write('Provide the ID')
_options = ['1', '2', '3']
default_client = "1"

with st.sidebar:
    _id = st.text_input("ID:","jhjkdkjhhkjhkj")
```

There is error in line `from google.auth import default` but when I launch streamlit using `streamlit run app.py` **it runs the entire code and throws the Traceback in the UI**.

How can I make sure the streamlit app stops as soon as its sees error without running the scanning the whole `app.py` and displays custom error message on the UI?

Answer (score 0):

Have you saved your file and/or rerun ?
Because I ran your code and I think it did exactly what you expected. There is no error stack and the page simply displays:
[image]

EDIT:
Following the comments, here is a piece of the script I use to run streamlit and to kill it:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

script_dir=$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" &>/dev/null && pwd -P)

echo "Script dir: ${script_dir}"

# streamlit rerun also reload imports in PYTHONPATH in case of modification
# : "${PYTHONPATH=${script_dir}/..:${script_dir}/../src:${script_dir}/../detr}"
: "${PYTHONPATH=${script_dir}/..}"

export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}"
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=""
export CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1

echo "PYTHONPATH: ${PYTHONPATH}"
if [ -f "${script_dir}/streamlit.log" ]; then
    echo "Removing previous file streamlit.log"
    rm "${script_dir}/streamlit.log"
fi

echo "Starting streamlit in 5s, [Ctrl + c] to abort ..."
sleep 2
echo "3s ..."
sleep 2
echo "1s ..."
sleep 1
echo "Running 'streamlit run ${script_dir}/demo_tt.py'"
echo "Please wait..."

nohup streamlit run "${script_dir}/demo_tt.py" >"${script_dir}/streamlit.log" 2>&1 &
echo $! >"${script_dir}/streamlit.pid"

while ! [ -s "${script_dir}/streamlit.log" ]; do
    sleep 1
done

cat "${script_dir}/streamlit.log"
echo "To follow logs :"
echo "tail -f ${script_dir}/streamlit.log"
```

And to kill it:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

script_dir=$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" &>/dev/null && pwd -P)

PID_FILE="${script_dir}/streamlit.pid"

if [ -f "${PID_FILE}" ]; then
    echo "Killing streamlit based on pid file: ${PID_FILE}"
    kill -9 "$(cat "${PID_FILE}")"
    rm "${PID_FILE}"
else
    kill -9 "$(ps aux | grep 'streamlit run' | grep <your_user_name> | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')"
fi
```

So as you can see , to answer your comment, I brutally kill all the processes which contain my_username and "streamlit run". Again, might not be the best practice but it does the job. Hopefully it will work too on MAC.

Comment: No it did not show it to me.  Which version streamlit are you using? Also how to stop all apps running on port in macbook?

Comment: I have Python3.10, streamlit==1.23.1, on WSL ubuntu.
Did not try but if you want to quit immediately maybe you can use exit(1) instead of st.stop()?. Otherwise in my case, I run streamlit with a shell script and keep the PID for killing later. I'll edit my answer with some info in case you are interested, but it might not be the best practice...